# PHP anonymous function variable as reference

Tags: php, function, reference, anonymous-function

While working with Laravel framework, more specific - Form macros, I stumbled upon a weird error.

At first, I thought it's something wrong with Laravel, but then I took everything out of context:

```
<?php

// placeholder function that takes variable as reference
$function = function(&$reference)
{
    // append to variable
    $reference = $reference . ':' . __METHOD__;
};

// test with straight call
$variable = 'something';
$function($variable);
echo $variable;


// test with call_user_func(), that gets called in Laravels case
$variable = 'something'; // reset
call_user_func($function, $variable);
echo $variable;
```

While the first call to `$function` executes properly, the second try with `call_user_func()`, produces (excerpt from Codepad):

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to {closure}() expected to be a reference, value given
PHP Warning: Parameter 1 to {closure}() expected to be a reference, value given
```

Fiddle: [Codepad @ Viper-7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vknzNO)

While writing this, I thought about `call_user_func_array()`: [fiddle here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ay57d8), but the same error is produced.

Have I got something wrong about references or is this a bug with PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would call this a bug with PHP, although it's technically a bug with `call_user_func`. The documentation does mention this, but perhaps not in a very enlightening way:

> Note that the parameters for `call_user_func()` are not passed by
>   reference.

It would be perhaps clearer to say that *the arguments to `call_user_func()` are not passed by reference* (but note that technically it's not necessary to say anything at all; this information is also embedded in the function signature).

In any case, this means is that when `call_user_func` finally gets to invoking its target callable, the `ZVAL` (PHP engine internal data structure for all types of values) for the argument being passed is not marked as "being-a-reference"; the closure checks this at runtime and complains because its signature says that the argument must be a reference.

In PHP < 5.4.0 it is possible to work around this by using call-time pass by reference:

```
 call_user_func($function, &$variable);
```

but this produces an `E_DEPRECATED` warning because call-time pass by reference is a deprecated feature, and will flat out cause a fatal error in PHP 5.4 because the feature has been removed completely.

Conclusion: there is no good way to use `call_user_func` in this manner.

Comment: Oh, didn't look up documentation for `call_user_func()`, read the page about anonymous functions. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Jon I don't think call-time pass by reference are available in PHP 5.4. You should get Fatal Error.

Comment: @PLB: Totally true, I had forgotten all about that. Thanks for the heads up, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
call_user_func_array($function, array(&$variable));
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this code

```
<?php
$myfunction = function &($arg=3)
{
    $arg = $arg * 2;
    return $arg;
};
echo $myfunction();
?>
```

Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do this?

```
call_user_func($function, &$variable);
```