# In PHP, how do you use a function as a parameter in another function?

Tags: php, function, parameters, closures, anonymous-function

I know that this question may have been asked before, but I don't quite understand the whole concept of anonymous functions (closures), and how they would apply specifically to my situation. NB: I know it is quite silly to have all these simple functions, but my task requirements say that I should have all these functions :/ .
I have several functions. In the function below, the parameters `$action1` and `$action2` will be both replaced by functions:

```
function dothis($num1, $num2, $action1, $action2)
{
    $result = $num1 + $num2;
    if ($result > 52){
        //do $action1 which is a function
    } else {
        //do $action2 which is another function
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The function `dothis` will be called in another function called `add`. Here is the `add` function:

```
function add($action1,$action2) 
{
     $answer = dothis(42, 34, $action1, $action2);
     echo $answer;
}
```

`$action1` and `$action2` in the `add` function are essentially the same as the `$action1` and `$action2` in the `dothis` function. Do they need to have different names now even though they are the same things?

Now, the `add` function will be called in the `main` function, where the parameters `$action1` and `$action2`, will be replaced by the actual functions that they correspond to:

```
function main() 
{
    add($fun1,$fun2);
    echo 'Arithmetic complete';
}
```

This is the code for `$fun1` and `$fun2`:

```
$fun1 = function () {
    echo 'Wow! The answer is greater than 52.';
};

$fun2 = function () {
    echo 'Oh no! The answer is less than 52.'; 
};
```

What should I do, and what do I need to change? I really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but when you assign a closure to a variable, you still need to terminate your assignments with `;`.

Comment: @localheinz Thanks! That's true. I completely forgot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the PHP documentation on [Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

You call a function by putting `()` after it (with arguments inside the parentheses if necessary).

```
function dothis($num1,$num2,$action1,$action2){
    $result = $num1 + $num2;
    if ($result > 52){
        $action1();
    }
    else{
        $action2();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

For this syntax to work with anonymous functions, you have to turn off eAccelerator. See [Anonymous functions does not work: Function name must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478729/anonymous-functions-does-not-work-function-name-must-be-a-string)

If you can't use anonymous functions, you'll need to use named functions.

```
function fun1 () {
    echo 'Wow! The answer is greater than 52.';
}
$fun1 = 'fun1';

function fun2() {
    echo 'Oh no! The answer is less than 52.';
}
$fun2 = 'fun2';
```

Comment: in the `dothis` function, `$action1` and `$action2` are still parameters; so they're not actually functions here yet. I tried to do that, but it gave me an error **Fatal error: Function name must be a string**. What should I do?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? This should work in PHP 5.3 and higher.

Comment: Weird. It works on my Mac running 5.3, but I get that error in ideone.com running 5.6.

Comment: I use 5.6 on windows.

Comment: See the question I just linked to in my answer. Turn off eAccelerator

Comment: Thanks! I do appreciate that advice, but i my circumstances, I'm not allowed to do that. I kind of have to stick to strict guidelines!

Comment: Then you'll have to create named functions, and assign the function names to `$fun1` and `$fun2`.

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean. If it is possible, can you show this in the actual code, because I'm getting a bit confused.

Comment: I added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but when before I call my `dothis` function in my `add` function, how do I use `$action1` and `$action2` as parameters? Do I just declare them like this: `if ($result > 52){$action1;}` ? I did that but it did't call the actual `$fun1` when I used `$fun1` as a parameter when I call `add` in the the `main` function.

Comment: You call them exactly the same way as I showed in my answer: `$action1()`. I've added a link to the PHP documentation.

Comment: @StephenGevanni: Then consider accepting Barmar's answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a rather bad approach. You could use a function like [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) but not really for [anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839622/php-anonymous-function-variable-as-reference). Why not come up with a class defining both functions or (if the code is rather short) but it in the if/else statements directly?

**Some dummy sample code for the class approach:**

```
class doSomething {

    function dothis($num1, $num2) {
        $result = $num1 + $num2;
        if ($result > 52) {
            $this->action1($num1, $num2);
        } else {
            $this->action2($num1, $num2);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function action1($numbers) {
        // do sth. here
    }

    function action2($num1, $num2) {
        // do sth. else here
    }
}

// afterwards
$pointer = new doSomething();
$pointer->dothis(21,34); // action1
$pointer->dothis(1,1);   // action2
```

Comment: thanks--> Now I completely get what you meant by the class defining the functions!